# Getting the Amps from Watts, Amps and the voltage of a line

Tags: education, mathematical-physics

What amperage capacity should the supplied wired be rated for a refrigerated fixture which has a 208V power supply and the following loads?

- 4 Evaporator fan motor rated at 9W each
- 4 Evaporator fan motor rated at 9W each
- 6 Florescent lights rated at 40W each
- 1 strip Mullion heater rated at 3 A

What I tried was:
(4*9W) + (4*9W) + (6*40W)+(3A*208V)= 936W
 Then I divided by 208V to get that to AMPS
936W/208V
this answer is 4.5
but the expect answer is 20A

Can someone please should how you would calculate this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No there isn't a typo. That is how the question is

Comment: I get the same results as you.

Comment: This assumes that everything is wired in parallel.

Comment: The question doesn't state it

Comment: Was a power factor given?

Comment: No there was no power factor given, That was the entire question. It as what amperage capacity be rated? not sure if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct given the data we have.  The motors will presumably have a higher starting current than running current, so in real life you need to allow for that.  20A is substantially higher than needed, however.

Answer (score 1):

i just spent an hour agonizing over that too....eventually found that question is missing some info. This guide has the correctly worded question...
www.aes.gov.nl.ca/app/exams/pdf/StudyGuide_RefrigAirCondMech.pdf‎

there are 2 defrost heaters not listed which add another 12 amps.